# area under precision-recall curve in R or matlab

Tags: matlab, classification

I have the predicted scores for a list of binary targets. What would be the best way to calculate the area under precision-recall curve using R or matlab?

I did some search on this and didn't find any relavant function/library to achieve this task. It seems odd because this should be a fairly common thing that people do. Not sure if I missed anything. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Below is matlab realization

```
function auc = scoreAUC(category,posterior)
% auc = scoreAUC(category,posterior)
%
% Calculates the area under the ROC for a given set
% of posterior predictions and labels. Currently limited to two classes.
%
% posterior: n1 matrix of posterior probabilities for class 1
% category: n1 matrix of categories {0,1}
% auc: Area under the curve
%
% Author: Benjamin Hamner
% Date Modified: October 14, 2010
%
% Algorithm found in
% A Simple Generalisation of the Area Under the ROC
% Curve for Multiple Class Classification Problems
% David Hand and Robert Till
% http://www.springerlink.com/content/nn141j42838n7u21/fulltext.pdf

r = tiedrank(posterior);
auc = (sum(r(category==1)) - sum(category==1) * (sum(category==1)+1)/2) / ...
( sum(category<1) * sum(category==1));
```